# How to add comments in JIRA ticket for any failed test case after build execution is completed in Jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, jira

I am running my Selenium test suit of 20 test cases as build from Jenkins and have integrated Jenkins with JIRA through Zephyr to update PASS/FAIL status of execution of each test case in their respective issues in JIRA.

Now I want to update or add comments in these issues for each failed test case (IF ANY) during execution in Build. So I tried using the "JIRA ISSUE UPDATER" plugin in Jenkins but it is not giving suitable results.

Instead, it only updates hard coded comments in JIRA for issue type IDs which we already provide in Jenkins project Configuration. I am using freestyle projects in Jenkins.